# OR Condition check multiple values possible?

Tags: php

I have no idea what I m looking for is called so I m asking if there is a way in php to check if one of multiple `hardcoded` value are true

What I mean is, is it possible to write the following condition

```
if($var == 'this' || $var == 'orthis') //this can become very long
```

By writing something similar like the following

```
if($var == 'this'||'orthis') //skiping the "||$var == " every value i want to check
```

I know I could technically just write the following

```
if(in_array($var,array('this','orthis')))
```

But I am currious to know if there is something like the second line.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't anything like that available in PHP

Comment: `in_array()` is generally the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: It's sad that i'm getting voted down with no comment explaining why, Especially when I think this question is a very possible good question.
Any how thanks to people that took the time to give input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a syntax like the `in` operator in SQL. But unfortunately for you there is no syntax for that, other than tricks like using `in_array`, like you suggested yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement

```
switch ($var) {
case 'this':
case 'orthis':
  // some code
  break;
}
```

Comment: True, Forgot about the switch :S